# Не могу читать с файла в android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В моем проекте имеются классы: `MainActivity`, `DAO`, `Question` и 1 `layout` -  `activity_main`. В классе `DAO` я считываю с файла `situations.txt` и передаю данные в `Question`. Потом в `MainActivity` я меняю текст одного `TextView` и двух кнопок на те, что лежат в соответствующих переменных в `Question`. Дебаг показал что ошибка(приложение вылетает) происходит на том месте, где меняется текст кнопок и `TextView`. Также в массиве `arr` с данными из `txt` ничего нет. Отсюда понятно что считывания не происходит. Также ошибка происходит при объявлении `txt` файла.

Код `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView situation;
Button button1;
Button button2;
Question q;
DAO dao;
ArrayList<Question> arr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    situation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.situation);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    dao = new DAO(this);
    //вылет приложения после строк выше
    arr = dao.getAll();
    q = arr.get(0);
    situation.setText(q.text);
    button1.setText(q.button1);
    button2.setText(q.button2);
}}
```

Код DAO:

```
public class DAO {
Context context;
public DAO(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
public ArrayList<Question> getAll() {
    ArrayList<Question> array = new ArrayList<Question>();
    AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream is = am.open("situations.txt");
        //сверху выдает ошибку
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, "$");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                Question q = new Question();
                q.text = st.nextToken();
                q.button1 = st.nextToken();
                q.button2 = st.nextToken();
                q.b1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                q.b2 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                q.life = Boolean.parseBoolean(st.nextToken());
                array.add(q);
                Log.v("a", "read");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return array;
}}
```

Situation.txt:

```
ttt$ff$ff$1$2$true
hh$6h$h8$1$2$true
```

Поля Question:

```
public class Question {
String text;
String button1;
String button2;
int b1;
int b2;
boolean life;}
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/situation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Situation"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="button2" />
```

Comment: В `MainActivity` вы объявляете переменную `q`, но никак её не инициализируете. То есть она `null`. Потом вы обращаетесь к её полям, поэтому приложение и вылетает.

Comment: а вы целенаправленно держите файл situations.txt открытым, или забыли его закрыть?

Comment: Раз `arr` не заполняется, то скорее всего у вас при чтении файла выбрасывается `IOException`. Смотрите логи в Android Monitor.

Comment: @eugeneek исправил код. Видимо ошибка действительно где-то в DAO

Comment: может файла и не существует... убедитесь что путь к файлу тот что вам нужен. + вы не закрываете открытый файл.

Comment: @test123 а как его закрывать и когда?

Comment: хм... очень филосовский вопрос... Вообще, рекомендуется закрыть его после того как работа с файлом завершена. В вашем случае, если это java8 можно использовать try-catch-finally с ресурсами, либо самостоятельно закрывать файл в блоке finally для более старых яв. Закрывается файл очень просто, волшебной командой интерфейса закрываемого ресурса: reader.close();

Comment: @test123 в DAO ошибка при определении текстового файла:
InputStream is = am.open("situations.txt");
закрытие файла в блоке как-то влияет на это?

Comment: @test123 закрытие файла не помогло

Comment: Предлагаю вам уже раскрыть наконец тайну, какую ошибку вы видите в логах.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью повторил ваш код - в Genymotion ошибка не воспроизвелась, обе строки из файла читает корректно - вероятно файл у вас лежит не в assets? Обратите внимание на структуру файлов на скриншотах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Действительно, все оказалось гораздо проще, у меня в названии файла не было расширения txt -> искал он в ассетах situations.txt, а был situation.